# How can I provision more PermGen space for my cloudbees jenkins maven build?

Tags: cloudbees

I've got [a build](https://gedcom.ci.cloudbees.com/job/gedcomx-snapshot/) that is consistently failing with "OOM: PermGen" space errors. I've attempted to adjust my MAVEN_OPTS with a pre-build `export` command to no avail. What else can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've written a wiki article on this: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Builds+failing+with+OutOfMemoryErrors

Answer (score 2):

setting MAVEN_OPTS on a pre build shell script will only apply to this shell script.
Use MAVEN_OPTS option in maven build step advanced options, or global MAVEN_OPTS to apply to all jobs http://JENKINS.INSTANCE/configure